# Access 2016 Prevent "change" event from firing

Tags: forms, ms-access, events

I have a combo box in an Access form with 2 values Yes / No.  The user opens the form and enters the reference number and pushes a button to run a macro.  The macro executes a query to return data based on the reference number.  The results of query are displayed in various text boxes.

After the combo box is built, the macro selects the appropriate value based on the query.  The problem I'm having is that the "change" event is triggered because the combo box is loaded for the first time.  I want to prevent this.

After reviewing the data, the user can choose to change the value in the combo box.  At this time, I want the change event to fire because the additional macros are run that update multiple tables in the database.

Can I prevent the "change" event from firing when the form is loaded with data but allow it to fire when the combo box is changed?

Thanks in advance for any help or suggestions you provide........

Comment: A module level boolean variable which defaults to False, and set to to True when the button macro is done. On the Change event, run your code only when its value is True.

Comment: Or use combobox AfterUpdate event instead of Change. I have never used Change event.

Comment: ^ This. Change is only needed for live search-as-you-type searching. For anything else, AfterUpdate is the right choice.

Comment: @KostasK.............Thanks..........That is what I ended up doing.  I appreciate the help...........

Comment: @Andre..........Thanks for the information......That is good to know.......